# Usage of @field annotations

Tags: scala, annotations

I was perusing the [spray-swagger](https://github.com/gettyimages/spray-swagger#model-definitions) library and came across this piece of code:

```
@ApiModel(description = "A pet object")
case class Pet(
  @(ApiModelProperty @field)(value = "unique identifier for the pet")
  val id: Int,

  @(ApiModelProperty @field)(value = "The name of the pet")
  val name: String)
```

I went to my trusty copy of Programming In Scala 3ed to find out what syntax of using the `@field` annotation within another annotation (re: `@(ApiModelProperty @field)`) but I came up short. I cracked open the `@ApiModelProperty` code and found:

```
/**
 * Adds and manipulates data of a model property.
 */
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface ApiModelProperty {
```

**Question:** Are we providing the compiler clues as to what context the `@ApiModelProperty` annotation applies in order to satisfy its `@Target` annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer in the [documentation for scala.annotation.target](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/annotation/target/package.html) package.

The `@field` meta-annotation is used to tell the compiler that the actual field named `id` should be considered the target of the annotation, as opposed to the automatically generated accesssor/mutator methods:
`id():Int` and `id_=(i: Int):()`.