# How can I set up bean validation for Scala case class with multiple levels of inheritance in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scala, bean-validation

### Problem Description

I'm having trouble validating overridden fields in a Scala case class using the Bean Validation API. Validation works properly for `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` annotations in the RestController.

### Code

#### RestController

```scala
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/my-endpoint")
class MyController(service: MyService) {

  @GetMapping(Array("/{id}/{version}"))
  def getByIds(
    @PathVariable @Pattern(regexp = @Pattern(regexp = "^([A-Z]{3}):([A-Za-z]*):([0-9A-Za-z_\\-]*)$")) id: String,
    @PathVariable @Pattern(regexp = @Pattern(regexp = "^([A-Z]{3}):([A-Za-z]*):([0-9A-Za-z_\\-]*)$")) version: String
  ): MyModel = getById(id, version)

  @PostMapping
  def create(@Valid @RequestBody entity: MyModel) ResponseEntity[Unit] = {
    service.create(entity)
  }
}
```

#### API model / Subclass

```scala
@AvroNamespace(AvroSchemaBuilder.baseNamespace)
@Schema(description = "MyModel")
case class MyModel(
  @NotNull
  @Pattern(regexp = ValidationPattern.netexIdPattern)
  @Schema(description = "Id", implementation = classOf[String], requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED) 
  override val id: String,

  @Pattern(regexp = ValidationPattern.netexIdPattern)
  @Schema(description = "Version", implementation = classOf[String], requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
  override val version: String
) extends SomeClassC
```

#### Superclasses

```scala
abstract class SomeClassC extends SomeClass B with SomeClassX {
}

abstract class SomeClass B extends SomeClassA {
  val name: List[SomeObject]
  val description: List[SomeObject]
}

abstract class SomeClassA {
  val id: String
  val version: String
}
```

### Debugging

After having stepped through the code, it looks like the `@Valid` annotation in the RestController is detected and evaluated as expected, whilst the bean validation annotations placed in the model class are not. This leads me to believe that the class is not registered by Spring, and hence, not exposed to the bean validation API. This assumption might be wrong, as I can see that the `valueContext` property of the `validateInContext` method in the `org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl` class is correctly referencing the model class - though all of the related to associated constraints are `0`.

### Attempted Solution

I've tried to annotate the model class and all superclasses with `@Component` to explicitly register them with Spring. However, this results in the following error related to the two overridden variables in the model:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found.

### Version of Languages and Frameworks

- Spring Boot `3.1.2`
- Scala `2.13.11`
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-`17.0.8+7`

I'm running a bit out of ideas on this one, so highly appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way modeling in Scala with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772213/what-is-the-best-way-modeling-in-scala-with-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work, unfortunately. I think it is the inheritance in play that messes up the validation somehow.

Comment: @GastónSchabas: My bad, the post didn't answer the question, but gave pointers in the right direction. See the solution in the comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tweak in the model class did the trick:

```scala
@AvroNamespace(AvroSchemaBuilder.baseNamespace)
@Schema(description = "MyModel")
case class MyModel(
  @(NotNull@field)
  @(Pattern@field)(regexp = "^([A-Z]{3}):([A-Za-z]*):([0-9A-Za-z_\\-]*)$")
  @Schema(description = "Id", implementation = classOf[String], requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED) 
  override val id: String,

  @(NotNull@field)
  @(Pattern@field)(regexp = "^([A-Z]{3}):([A-Za-z]*):([0-9A-Za-z_\\-]*)$")
  @Schema(description = "Version", implementation = classOf[String], requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
  override val version: String
) extends SomeClassC
```

The solution was to add the `@field` annotation to all the constraints that are set on a given field. If I've understood things correctly this was needed "*because that meta-annotation is used to tell the compiler that the actual field should be considered the target of the annotation, as opposed to the automatically generated accesssor/mutator methods"* (reference from another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014280/usage-of-field-annotations))